# Specific Method of Summing n Number of Array values Together With Recursion (Javascript Algorithm)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

**This is the question**

Write a recursive function, sum(arr, n), that returns the sum of the first n elements of an array arr.

**Attempt I Found on The Internet**

```js
  function multiply(arr, n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return multiply(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
    }
  }
```

**My Question To You**

*1. How does the else statement work?*

I can't understand what we are adding arr[n - 1] to.

*2. Is there a simpler way of writing this code?*

Comment: 1.) Basically this is how recursion works. We add arr[n - 1] to the result of the next call (n-2) and so on until the index = 0 is reached. This recursion works from the biggest to the lowest index element in the array.

2.) This is already a quite simple way of achieving this by recursion. If you want to sum up elements you need this statement `return multiply(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];` in some form (a recursive call + the the current one).

Comment: But I'm pretty sure the code does not return the correct sum. Hence I will add an answer providing the correct code.

Comment: That helps a lot, but because the formula only returns 1, how does the first part of the else statement provide anything that is useful to add to arr[n-1]. E.g. if the arr was: [1, 2, 3, 4] and n was 3, what would the return multiply(arr, n - 1) represent through the first two cycles of the loop

Comment: I updated my answer. Please check if this now answers the specific case of n=3 and the array [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered the question in the comments. From my understanding the code you posted does not return the correct result. This is how it should look like:

```
  function multiply(arr, n) {
    if (n <= 0) { // return 0 if count is 0 or negative
      return 0;
    } else { // sum up the next n - 1 elements with the current element
      return multiply(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];
    }
  }
```

Actually for `n=0` the result should be 0 and not 1, also when adding any arbitrary array you would get a wrong result with `return 1`. It should be `return 0`. E.g. [5,4,3,2] = 14 (old version 15).

As I'm now answering I will also attach my comment below:

1.) Basically this is how recursion works. We add arr[n - 1] to the result of the next call (n-2) and so on until the index = 0 is reached. This recursion works from the biggest to the lowest index element in the array.

2.) This is already a quite simple way of achieving this by recursion. If you want to sum up elements you need this statement: `return multiply(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1];` in some form (a recursive call + the the current element).

**Update to the question in the comments:**

`var arr = [1,2,3,4], n = 3;`

1. call: `multiply(arr, n-1)`(value=0 plus 1 plus 2) + `arr[n-1]`(value=3)
2. call: `multiply(arr, n-2)`(value=0 plus 1) + `arr[n-2]`(value=2)
3. call: `multiply(arr, n-3)`(value=0) + `arr[n-3]`(value=1)
4. call: terminate because of 0 (value=0)

And now think about it a bit differently. Until recursion termination nothing has summed up. And also in the 4. call nothing is summed as we did not enter the else branch.

Hence, the first sum calculated would be:

0(n-4) **+ 1(n-3)**.

This will be returned and the next calculation would be:

(0(n-4) + 1(n-3)) **+ 2(n-2)**.

The last sum calculated is also the final result:

(0(n-4) + 1(n-3) + 2(n-2)) **+ 3(n-1)**.

Every recursion needs two things:

1. a recursive call
2. a condition to terminate

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of what multiply(arr, n - 1) would represent. E.g. if arr was [1, 2, 3, 4] and n was 3

Comment: Because it confuses me that you can add anything to an array and a number as two separate arguments.

Comment: @AndrewNeedsHelp I added an additional information to my answer I think this should help understanding. I will get back on that answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

First off, that function is incorrect. I can't really tell you what it's trying to do, but it's certainly not adding the first n elements of an array. So how do we approach about writing one? And what's recursion?

Recursion didn't start as a programming idea, it's one that started with mathematics, like a lot of other programming constructs. So before we write the sum function, let's define it mathematically:

```
f(arr, 0) = 0
f(arr, n) = f(n - 1) + arr[n - 1]
```

I know arrays aren't used as such in math, but what the hell, this is still useful to look at. First thing that one should notice is that there are *two* definitions, not one. The first definition says: The sum of the first 0 elements of an array arr is always 0. No matter what happened before or after, it will always be 0.

The second definition says that to sum the first n elements of an array arr, we must find the sum of the previous elements, then simply add the `arr[n - 1]`. **Another way to think about it, the sum of the first n elements, is just the sum of the first n - 1 elements plus the nth element**. This might cause headaches, no, it will cause headaches. So to mitigate your pain, we'll be taking a look at it step by step.

Say I pass the function `f([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)`, I should get 3. Here's how the function evaluates to 3:

```
f([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) = f([1, 2, 3, 4], 1) + [1, 2, 3, 4][1]
f([1, 2, 3, 4], 1) = f([1, 2, 3, 4], 0) + [1, 2, 3, 4][0]
f([1, 2, 3, 4], 0) = 0
```

And we're done. What? We're done? We sure are. Notice how we defined each function call we made? That means we can work our way backwards and substitute each function call with the definition. So:

```
f([1, 2, 3, 4], 0) = 0
f([1, 2, 3, 4], 1) = 0 + 1 = 1
f([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) = 1 + 2 = 3
```

Simply by writing out definitions, we are able to evaluate the answer. It might be tricky to think about, but evaluating it doesn't get any simpler, which is why there's a lot of praise for recursive functions. Anyways, we've defined it mathematically, we can now really easily implement it in JavaScript, or really any language of your choice -- as long as it supports recursion.

```
function sum(arr, n)
{
    if (n <= 0) return 0; // f(arr, 0) = 0
    return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1]; // f(arr, n) = f(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1]
}
```

A couple of things to notice. You can't have recursion if the function doesn't return something, since evaluation the function relies on substitution. And every recursive function needs to have at least two definitions, that way the loop can end. Also, you see how the code almost matches the math definitions one to one? I know, it's really awesome.

Edit: `if (n == 0)` is fine, but it doesn't work if n is negative. So, I replaced it with `n <= 0`.

Comment: Great approach by explaining it mathematically. Very liked your writing style as well :P.

Comment: Thanks! I find that debugging recursive functions in a "math" way is very useful in general, so I figure I'd do the same to explain it.

Comment: You guys are great!